# How to add callback to hide and show a div on form submit with this JQuery validation code

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, event-handling

I am trying to add one more bit of functionality to this code from Joren Rapini's blog, it's a simple form validator. Because of the nature of the project, I do not have much access to testing to do any real AJAX submit or refresh page functionality. So I am trying to use the validation code, but in addition, once all required fields are filled in, and the submit button becomes 'active' by it's return being set to true, I want to a) hide the form container div and b) show a previously hidden div.

So we have this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Place ID's of all required fields here.
required = ["first_name", "last_name", "email", "street_address"];
// If using an ID other than #email or #error then replace it here
email = $("#email");
errornotice = $("#error");
// The text to show up within a field when it is incorrect
emptyerror = "Please fill out this field.";
emailerror = "Please enter a valid e-mail.";

$("#unique-form").submit(function(){    
    //Validate required fields
    for (i=0;i<required.length;i++) {
        var input = $('#'+required[i]);
        if ((input.val() == "") || (input.val() == emptyerror)) {
            input.addClass("needsfilled");
            input.val(emptyerror);
            errornotice.fadeIn(750);
        } else {
            input.removeClass("needsfilled");
        }
    }
    // Validate the e-mail.
    if (!/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(email.val())) {
        email.addClass("needsfilled");
        email.val(emailerror);
    }

    //if any inputs on the page have the class 'needsfilled' the form will not submit
    if ($(":input").hasClass("needsfilled")) {
        return false;
    } else {
        errornotice.hide();
        return true;
    $("#placeHolder #myForm").hide();
    $("#placeHolder #stuff").show();
    }
});

// Clears any fields in the form when the user clicks on them
$(":input").focus(function(){       
   if ($(this).hasClass("needsfilled") ) {
        $(this).val("");
        $(this).removeClass("needsfilled");
   }
}); });
```

And my code is this bit:

```
$("#placeHolder #myForm").hide();
    $("#placeHolder #stuff").show();
```

This doesn't work. I am trying to hide a thank you message and some social media links in the #stuff div, to basically replicate an AJAX load of a thank you page on submission of the form. But I am limited with the client, I will not have the ability to do a lot of back and forth testing with the server, I am trying to just rig a very simple front end solution to this. The validation part seems to work as needed, and I have all of the div ids correct in the code, so I know it is some concept in the structure of this event handling that I just don't get yet, and I have a deadline approaching so I am reaching out for help if anyone has any ideas.

I know I am missing something in the structure, or the syntax, but not sure what it is. Do I need to write a separate function and then call that instead? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
I am reposting a stripped down version of the code I am using, for clarity's sake. I am trying to hide the containing element of the form (the id I am using for the containing element is actually "#form-holder" and the initially hidden div is "#thank-you". My problem is not with the selectors, it's in the javascript/ jQuery logic (well, it's my NOT understanding the logic :) - or it also could be due to the inherit logic of clicking a form submit button. As I state in my comments, I see the hidden div for the briefest moment, then it reverts back to display none. Right now this is Greek text just to get it working, what it will eventually be is a 'Thank You' text message with Twitter links, etc - but I just need to get the logic right and functioning first.

```
                $(document).ready(function(){
// Place ID's of all required fields here.
required = ["email"];
// If using an ID other than #email or #error then replace it here
email = $("#email");
errornotice = $("#error");
formholder = $('#form-holder');
thankyou = $("#thank-you");
// The text to show up within a field when it is incorrect
emptyerror = "Please fill out this field.";
emailerror = "Please enter a valid e-mail.";

$("#myForm").submit(function(){ 
    //Validate required fields
    for (i=0;i<required.length;i++) {
        var input = $('#'+required[i]);
        if ((input.val() == "") || (input.val() == emptyerror)) {
            input.addClass("needsfilled");
            input.val(emptyerror);
            errornotice.fadeIn(750);
        } else {
            input.removeClass("needsfilled");
        }
    }
    // Validate the e-mail.
    if (!/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(email.val())) {
        email.addClass("needsfilled");
        email.val(emailerror);
    }

    //if any inputs on the page have the class 'needsfilled' the form will not submit
    if ($(":input").hasClass("needsfilled")) {
        return false;
    } else {
        errornotice.hide();
        formholder.hide();
        thankyou.show();
        return true;
    }
});

// Clears any fields in the form when the user clicks on them
$(":input").focus(function(){       
   if ($(this).hasClass("needsfilled") ) {
        $(this).val("");
        $(this).removeClass("needsfilled");
   }
});});</script>
```

And you can see that I added my formholder and thankyou in as variables near the top of the code. Below is a version of the HTML.

```
 <div id="form-holder">
<form id="myForm" class="form">
<p class="names form-paragraph clearfix">
<span class="first_name">
<label for="name">First Name</label>
<input type="text" required="required" name="first_name" id="first_name" /></span>
<span class="last_name">
<label for="name">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" required="required" name="last_name" id="last_name" /></span>
</p>
<p class="email form-paragraph">
<label for="email">Email*</label>
<input type="text" required="required" name="email" id="email" />
</p><p id="error">There were errors on the form, please make sure all fields are fill out correctly.</p>
<p class="small-text">* Required Field</p>
<p class="submit"><span><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="formSubmit" /></span>
<span><button type="reset" value="RESET">RESET</button></span></p></form>
<div id="thank-you"><p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui    blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.</p></div>
```

Comment: id's must be unique so this selector doesn't make much sense `$("#placeHolder #myForm")`...

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment - the selector's I mentioned where meant to be abstract, I have reposted with the actual code and how it relates to the HTML markup -thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have'nt looked very hard at that code, but you have added your two lines of code after the return true statement, so the function will terminate and return true before your code ever runs, so it does'nt really matter what you write, it will never be executed.

You need to move your code up a notch, before the return statement, and then maybe it will work, if the code is correct, something that is impossible to tell as we don't know the markup and can't really say much about your choice of selectors.

```
if ($(":input").hasClass("needsfilled")) {
    return false;
} else {
    errornotice.hide();
    //the below seems like strange selectors, they could be valid, 
    //but just using the latter would suffice as they are ID's
    $("#placeHolder #myForm").hide(); 
    $("#placeHolder #stuff").show();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I actually just figured out moments ago that my .hide(); and .show(); methods indeed need to come before the the return true; - just as you have mentioned here. So when I place the show(); before the return true, I see the #stuff div show up on the page for a split second, then the form actually 'returns true' and the #stuff div hides again (I have it hidden by default with display:none; in CSS.

Comment: So what is happening, I think and please correct me if my terminology is wrong, that the form is resetting itself after I click the submit button, and returning to the default state. Mind you, the form currently is not sending anywhere, this is all being tested locally in HTML. So the question is, how do I allow it to submit, yet not 'reset', but rather proceed to the next step which is to a) hide the first div, and b) show the second div (#placeHolder and #stuff respectively) - thank you again!

Comment: I updated my original post above with a more accurate view of the code in use and perhaps this helps clarify what I am trying to do

Comment: Your form is doing what's its supposed to do, submitting, does not matter if it's not submitting anywhere special, it's still submitting which will make the page reload, like hitting F5. You will have to prevent the default behavior, like so : `$("#myForm").submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });` just add the "e" in your function(e goes here), and stick the `e.preventDefault();` at the top of your function.

Comment: Thank you Adeneo, I had thought about e.preventDefault(); as I have used it before on click events on regular links, so thank you for pointing that out. And when I add it to the code, it does as you say - it allows for my show() and hide() to work - however, it doesn't submit the data - or will it submit the data once I 'hook the form up' and it has the POST action url, etc?

Comment: Because I am trying to get it to submit the data, (when it is live) and then, do the show() and hide() methods - I feel like I'm having a very weird mental block on this. Is this something I can even do without AJAX - maybe just extend this code slightly - say, if the form is submitted, do the show/hide - but not from a server response, simply building on the code above and having this take place all on the front end.

Comment: No, it will not submit the form with the default action when using preventDefault(), to do that you will have to submit it with Ajax, otherwise the site will always refresh when the form is submitted, so yes, only solution to stop the page from refreshing is to use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Based on everyone's comments, and from the final comments from Adeneo, I came to realize that it was not possible to achieve what I was trying to do, in the way originally planned. So I am currently trying a very simple AJAX validation/ submit based on the tutorial over on Nettuts+, here (and keeping my fingers crossed): http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

From Adeneo:

*No, it will not submit the form with the default action when using preventDefault(), to do that you will have to submit it with Ajax, otherwise the site will always refresh when the form is submitted, so yes, only solution to stop the page from refreshing is to use ajax.*

Thanks for everyone's help.